# harp.gl and angular ng

Tags: angular, typescript, harp.gl

> We are using harp.gl in an ng angular application, but are having trouble connecting to data sources in the same way that worked in our yarn demo.
>   We create the datasource as:

```
const dataSource = new OmvDataSource({
  baseUrl: "https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc",
  apiFormat: APIFormat.XYZOMV,
  styleSetName: "tilezen",
  authenticationCode: apikey,
  authenticationMethod: {
        method: AuthenticationMethod.QueryString,
        name: "apikey"
  }
});
```

and create a MapView as:

```
const mapView = new MapView({
    canvas: mapCanvas,
    theme: "assets/resources/berlin_tilezen_base.json",
    // note, this URL may vary depending on configuration of webpack
    // for this example, it is assumed that app is server from project root
    decoderUrl: "harp-gl-decoders.bundle.js"
    // note, this URL may vary depending on configuration of webpack
    // for this example, it is assumed that webpack emits bundles to project root
});
```

and add the data source thus:

```
mapView.addDataSource(dataSource);
```

and see this at the console:

```
[WDS] App updated. Reloading...  
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.  
MapView: Failed to connect to datasource anonymous-datasource#1: Error during worker initialization  
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

and this at the debug console of the webpage:

```
:4200/decoder.bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
ConsoleChannel.js:15 MapView: Failed to connect to datasource anonymous-datasource#1: Error during worker initialization
```

I have spent many hours grasping at straws and would accept any help.

Answer (score 0):

As [seen here](https://www.harp.gl/docs/master/doc/classes/harp_mapview.workerloader.html#startworker), you may need an additional meta tag in your page head

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src blob:">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently a getting started guide for Angular was added here:
https://github.com/heremaps/harp.gl/blob/master/docs/GettingStartedAngular.md

Almost at the end it adds the decoder.bundle.js to the asset section of the angular.json:

```
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "decoder.bundle.js",
            "input": "./",
            "output": "./"
          }
        ],
```